# Dynamic initialization of ArrayList<anyClassObject>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Normally if we want to initialize a generic non-primitive ArrayList we do this

```
ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass.class>();
```

But I want to do something similar to this no matter which class object I pass, i.e

```
private void getModel(Class responseType){

   //Something similar, because this does not work..                                                       
   ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<responseType>();
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about this private void getModel(T extends Object){                                                   
   ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
}

Comment: what you want to do ??

Comment: Generics is for compile time type-safety. `ArrayList<MyType>` is type-erased to `ArrayList` after compilation. It's not possible to invoke `new ArrayList<MyType>()` at runtime, you have to call `new ArrayList()`.

Comment: @Vinoth please elaborate 

This doesn't work as well 
                     ArrayList<? extends responseType>  arrayList = (ArrayList<? extends responseType>) new ArrayList<Class>();

Comment: @BheshGurung any other way if this is not possible, because I am populating models at runtime and I need a responseType

Comment: `new ArrayList<MyType>()` is valid, `new ArrayList<MyType.class>()` is not valid.

Comment: If you want to instantiate it at dynamically then you have to use the non-generic version, which of course works for any type.

Comment: @BheshGurung that means I have to write 9 different functions for populating 9 different models ?

Comment: You haven't yet properly demostrated what your real requirement is.

Comment: I want to pass a class in a function and initialize an ArrayList with that

Comment: You said you have to populate 9 different lists, can you show exactly how and where are they declared?

Comment: @BheshGurung I have multiple models
1) ModelA
2) ModelB
3) ModelC
etc..

The Models cannot be populated within a controller.. they have to be populated by a layer (Following Facade design pattern). The Facade will call some api and a json will be returned, here dynamic mapping will happen on the basis of KVO and I will receive an object POPULATED with the MODEL which I have supplied. This all happens in a function. I want to pass the Model from the controller in this specific function through FacadeLayer. This is much more complex than this.

Comment: that's why I need this    ArrayList<responseType> arrayList = new ArrayList<responseType>(); but this is wrong I need something similar to this..

Comment: It's not quite clear what your are actually doing and trying to achieve. By the way, getXXX methods are normally not void, they usually return something.

Comment: @BheshGurung yes it returns an ArrayList of the populated data, I was showing with an example:
  private ArrayList<?> getModel(Class responseType){
  {
   //Here ...
   }

Comment: @BheshGurung I don't think how much I can explain to be clear...
simple question
Q1) Initialize an ArrayList with a non-primitive data type which you dont know ? (How will you answer this ?)

Comment: Look at my post. this may be solution that you're looking for

Comment: I already wrote that you cannot initialize a list of some type that you don't you about. Your only option is to use the non generic version `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this

```
     private <T> void setModel(Class<T> type) {
      ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
   }
```

If you want to get the list back then

```
private <T> ArrayList<T> getModel(Class<T> type) {
      ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
      return arrayList;
   }
```

**EDIT**

**A FULL EXAMPLE SHOWING HOW TO USE GENERIC TYPE FOR ARRAYLIST**

Tester class with main method and the generic Method

```
public class Tester {

    private <T> ArrayList<T> getModels(Class<T> type) {
        ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
        return arrayList;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data data = new Data(12, "test_12");
        Magic magic = new Magic(123, "test_123");

        Tester t = new Tester();

        ArrayList<Data> datas = (ArrayList<Data>) t.getModels(Data.class);
        datas.add(data);
        for(Data data2 : datas) {
            System.out.println(data2);
        }

        ArrayList<Magic> magics = (ArrayList<Magic>) t.getModels(Magic.class);
        magics.add(magic);
        for(Magic magic2 : magics) {
            System.out.println(magic2);
        }

    }

}
```

Another possibility to use the same things without parameter since we don't use it inside the method

```
public class Tester {

    private <T> ArrayList<T> getModel() {
        ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
        return arrayList;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data data = new Data(12, "test_12");
        Magic magic = new Magic(123, "test_123");

        Tester t = new Tester();

        ArrayList<Data> datas =  t.getModel();
        datas.add(data);
        for(Data data2 : datas) {
            System.out.println(data2);
        }

        ArrayList<Magic> magics = t.getModel();
        magics.add(magic);
        for(Magic magic2 : magics) {
            System.out.println(magic2);
        }

    }

}
```

Model class (Data)

```
public class Data {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;


    public Data() {
    }


    public Data(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [" + (id != null ? "id=" + id + ", " : "") + (name != null ? "name=" + name : "") + "]";
    }

}
```

Model class (Magic)

```
public class Magic {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;


    public Magic() {
    }


    public Magic(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [" + (id != null ? "id=" + id + ", " : "") + (name != null ? "name=" + name : "") + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `Class<T>` parameter, since it's never used. Just leave it off and the type will be inferred from the call site. Of course, then you've just reinvented Guava's `Lists.newArrayList()` method.

Comment: @Festus where you are casting the class type ? i.e Class<T> type ?

Comment: you are not using `type`. Why not declare it as `private <T> ArrayList<T> getModels()`?

Comment: @FestusTamakloe: yeah, it is possible that the compiler will have issues inferring T in some cases if you remove that parameter, but the caller can always explicitly specify it

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
private void getModel(){
   ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
}
```

I mean, it is unclear what you are trying to do. Generics is purely compile-timem, to perform compile-time type checking. Therefore, if the type parameter is not known at compile time, it would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following

```
public <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> requiredType) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}

public void useList() {
    List<Integer> ints = getList(Integer.class);
    List<String> lists = getList(String.class);
}
```

Comment: well in this case, you are not using `requiredType`. Why not just declare it as `public <T> List<T> getList()`?

Comment: if you have a scenario where you are aware of the class type of the object (may be you are loading some data from a file which has class name info etc) then the above method would be useful. Because otherwise you will have to cast to the correct type with if/else checks. But you are right .. other than in such a scenario we can simply have T or simply need not have a method like this at all