# Set Type of ArrayList Dynamically

Tags: java, arraylist

Currently I have this set of code:

```
package com.sdqn.shared.property;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Misc_ReturnValue {
    public String message;
    public int total;
    public boolean success;
    public ArrayList results;

    public Misc_ReturnValue(){
        this.success = false;
        this.total = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I need the `results` to accept any type. I try to follow the answer from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697775/dynamic-initialization-of-arraylistanyclassobject)** but it seem like I don't understand how to use it in my code. Can anybody explain to me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand your code, can you explain where your return type is supposed to be?

Comment: @IvanLing, this is just a property class - does this information helpful enough?

Comment: `ArrayList<T> results= new ArrayList<T>();` what else you want?

Comment: @prashantthakre I did already what you are suggesting but it doesn't work at all. `T` is not recognized as generic type. You can give it a try.

Comment: I posted my answer please check if it fits to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Misc_ReturnValue<T> {
    public String message;
    public int total;
    public boolean success;
    public ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();

    public Misc_ReturnValue(){
        this.success = false;
        this.total = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I use this property? I tried to use them but 500 Error returned.