# how to get List of generic type from spring hateoas traverson

Tags: generics, java-8, spring-data-rest, spring-4, spring-hateoas

Consider my following code. I am trying to get list of objects based on the generic responseType using spring-hateoas Traverson class

```
    public <T> ArrayList<T> getList(String path, Class<T> responseType) {
    String url = decodeURL(host + path);

    try {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<T>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<T>>() {
        };
        Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI(url), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
        Resources<T> t = traverson.follow().toObject(typeReference);

        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.addAll(t.getContent());

        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my common method, using this method I am requesting many REST API with different type of object. For example

```
List<User> users = getList("/users", User.class);
```

Till now all is working fine. But when iterating users it throws the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.foo.data.User
```

Any idea? What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<T>>` is not capable of capturing the actual type of `T`. You should consider using the `responseType` argument, which *is* already a captured specification of `T`. I’m not into these frameworks, but I bet, there is a way to tell it that you want a list of the type…

Comment: This is not working. I am getting compilation error while using responseType as a Resources<T>

Comment: Nobody said that you can use a `Class<T>` as a drop-in replacement. Consult the documentation to find out how you can specify that you want a `List` of the type, represented by a `Class` object. Otherwise, you can remove that parameter, if it doesn’t help you at all, and let the caller pass a `ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<User>>` instead of `User.class`…

Comment: I referred this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697775/dynamic-initialization-of-arraylistanyclassobject/15698192#15698192 to pass type T instead of responseType.

Comment: But as the [first comment to the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697775/dynamic-initialization-of-arraylistanyclassobject/15698192#comment22291555_15698192) already states, the `Class<T>` parameter serves no actual purpose there. Since the method’s only purpose is to return a `new ArrayList<>()`, the entire method is obsolete and does not provide any advantage over the straight forward direct instantiation at the caller’s place. This works, as `ArrayList` is truly generic, it does not depend on the actual element type.

Comment: But you want `toObject(…)` to return instances of the correct actual type.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127077/discussion-between-achaius-and-holger).

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing this problem right now.